# Filtering and Comparing List of Two Items

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, sails.js

This is a Sails.js and Node.js application. I am trying to solve a problem I am having. I don't know which way to go to solve it. Which is why the title of my question doesn't really conform with it.

But, this is the scenario. I've this:

### LIST OF ORDERS

```
{
    "vehicleType": "30tonne",
    "waybill": "7006722988",
    "obdCreationDate": "01/11/16 1:21:50 PM",
    "route": "5817895991a297ccb386469d",
    "source": "agbara",
    "destination": "ilorin",
    "batchNumber": "ebf96f3322320fb2bedb7bf126f87ab8367f5bd6061cde78ab300e464df2c7af"
  },
  {
    "vehicleType": "30tonne",
    "waybill": "7006691063",
    "obdCreationDate": "01/11/16 1:21:50 PM",
    "route": "5817895e91a297ccb38646d9",
    "source": "agbara",
    "destination": "katsina",
    "batchNumber": "ebf96f3322320fb2bedb7bf126f87ab8367f5bd6061cde78ab300e464df2c7af"
  },
```

And I've this:

### LIST OF TRANSPORTERS

```
    {
        "vehicles": [
          {
            "assetIdentification": "EWEW",
            "vehicleType": "na",
            "transporter": "5817891891a297ccb38645c1",
            "organization": "5817878612a8dce1b2e4d359",
            "status": "available",
            "isDeleted": false,
            "createdAt": "2016-10-31T18:20:32.963Z",
            "updatedAt": "2016-10-31T18:20:32.963Z",
            "id": "5800c3cc391eaa0709cffee5"
          },
          {
            "assetIdentification": "RERE",
            "vehicleType": "na",
            "transporter": "5817891891a297ccb38645c1",
            "organization": "5817878612a8dce1b2e4d359",
            "status": "available",
            "isDeleted": false,
            "createdAt": "2016-10-31T18:20:32.965Z",
            "updatedAt": "2016-10-31T18:20:32.965Z",
            "id": "5800c4d9391eaa0709cffee6"
          }
        ],
        "rates": [
          {
            "fixedCost": 280759,
            "variableCost": 0,
            "vehicleType": "30tonne",
            "organization": "5817878612a8dce1b2e4d359",
            "route": "5817894b91a297ccb38645f9",
            "transporter": "5817891891a297ccb38645c1",
            "tripType": "normal",
            "active": true,
            "isDeleted": false,
            "totalCost": 280759,
            "createdAt": "2016-10-31T18:14:33.668Z",
            "updatedAt": "2016-10-31T18:14:33.668Z",
            "id": "58178a093ee3f7ffb3b14a47",
            "_route": "5817894b91a297ccb38645f9"
          },
          {
            "fixedCost": 280759,
            "variableCost": 0,
            "vehicleType": "30tonne",
            "organization": "5817878612a8dce1b2e4d359",
            "route": "5817894b91a297ccb38645fa",
            "transporter": "5817891891a297ccb38645c1",
            "tripType": "normal",
            "active": true,
            "isDeleted": false,
            "totalCost": 280759,
            "createdAt": "2016-10-31T18:14:33.866Z",
            "updatedAt": "2016-10-31T18:14:33.866Z",
            "id": "58178a093ee3f7ffb3b14a66",
            "_route": "5817894b91a297ccb38645fa"
          }
        ],
        "organization": "5817878612a8dce1b2e4d359",
        "name": "Some Organization",
        "email": "sosoos@soso.so",
        "phone": "8392398293829",
        "active": true,
        "isDeleted": false,
        "slug": "some-orgs",
        "createdAt": "2016-10-31T18:10:32.623Z",
        "updatedAt": "2016-10-31T18:10:32.623Z",
        "id": "5817891891a297ccb38645c1"
      }
```

That record above (Transporters) is over 9000 and each transporter have `rates` over 200. And, the one before that (ORDERS) can come in any size.

So, this is the problem. Every Orders have `routeId` and `vehicleType`. Transporters have `Array of vehicles with vehicleSize (s)`, `Array of rates which each have rateId, vehicleType and totalCost(Cost for that route)`. The problem I am trying to solve is to get the *cheapest* rate to complete all the orders even if assigning 1 order to every transporter would make it cheap. I wrote one which I was having loops within loops to do all forms of combination and it got me the cheapest. But, running it against `30 Orders` rendered the app unavailable for any other request and with 7GB dedicated RAM, we still run out of Memory every now and then and since `JavaScript` is synchronous, that would surely make the port the app's running useless unless it's done with that operation. `30 Orders` takes 30mins to an hour.

I couldn't think of what to do. I tried going through if `Permutation` and `Combination` can solve it, but no. I'm not looking for a fully written solution. I just need suggestions on what to do and how to go about it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: 1. in your script use only data that you need for performing this test. You don't need ```createdAt```, ```updatedAt``` and many more columns. It will decrease memory useage.
2. Take a look at Lodash. There are many functions that may help you solving this. For example ```.map()```, ```.sortBy()```

Comment: I use `Lodash` throughout my implementation

Answer (score 0):

It is a classical [A* pathfinding task](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm). To optimise you should create reverse index [vehicleType,route]=>[vehicle] with minimum rate for every combination of vehicleType and route, it takes single iteration through all rates, e.g. O(r). Then going through every order you can assign relevant vehicle from the index. It does not account for active and availability flags and same vehicle might be assigned multiple orders, but it will be easy to improve extending above index with array of resulting vehicles ordered by the price.

Reverse index is best to be built on a database side via map-reduce. Though you can build it in the node too:

```
let ratesByRouteVType = []
transporters
  .rates
    .forEach(r => {
       let cmpRate = ratesByRouteVType[r.route+r.vehicleType]
       if(!cmpRate || cmpRate.totalCost>r.totalCost)
         ratesByRouteVType[r.route+r.vehicleType]=r
     })
```